# I just created an HTML 5 Boilerplate project in WebStorm. Is there a standard command for compiling the "dist" folder?

Tags: html, webstorm, html5boilerplate

I'm getting started with WebStorm 9. I created an HTML 5 Boilerplate project and I noticed a `src` and a `dist` folder.

Is there a standard command to compile the content of the `src` folder into the `dist` folder?

This is how my project looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like HTML5 Boilerplate comes with a `gulpfile.js` file, so it looks like it wants to use [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) to build assets from `src` into `dist`.

If you have Gulp installed, you can run `gulp build` in your project directory.

If you don't have Gulp installed, you should install it with [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/). HTML5 Boilerplate has a `package.json` file that includes Gulp, so install npm and then run `npm install` in your project directory, and that should install everything that HTML5 Boilerplate expects.

Comment: I installed npm, installed gulp, installed number of packages gulp requires and now I have: [23:58:58] 'lint:js' errored after 12 ms
[23:58:58] AssertionError: path must be a string
    at Module.require (module.js:362:3)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at requireFn (/opt/extra/work/temp/WebstormProjects/test/node_modules/gulp-load-plugins/index.js:37:14)

Comment: What do you mean installed a number of packages gulp requires? You installed npm and then all you need to do is run npm install. Did you navigate inside gulpfile.js and install all required packages one by one? That's just going to be pull the latest versions and that's not always what you want. What's in the package.json should be used. Start a new project.

Comment: Actually, you need `npm install --dev`

Answer (score 3):

If you are using webStorm: just right click the `package.json`, you will find something like `run npm install`. It will do everything for you. After this right click the `gulpfile.js` file, and choose show Gulp tasks. Then you will find what you can do in Gulp window.

Comment: I'm using these steps and getting a load of npm WARN deprecated, several of which warn of 'avoid a RegExp DoS issue'. I'm guessing I need to update something?